# Make http connection accessible in server busy mode

Tags: c#, http

I want to access a site (3rd party, I have no server side access to it) via HttpClient in c#. All works well but without a fact. I want to access the site most at a certain time of the day, for 3-4 minutes. But this time the server flooded by user requests and server sends http response code 504.

The time is almost fixed, that is when I want to get contents from it.And it gets   inaccisible for that time due to loads of user hits.

Is there any technique, (such as Keep-Alive header) that can maximize my chance to get response from that site when it even gets busy? I search a lot but found nothing. If you could help me, I would be grateful. Thanks guys.

I'am Adding here normal time request and response header for your further understanding....
**REQUEST HEADER**

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://somesite.com/Appointment.jsp
Cookie: x-bni-ca=2057692237; JSESSIONID=E52C0DEE598BBABAAC74736A09F553B8.bgd-5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 82
```

**RESPONSE HEADER**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Fri, 31 Jul 2015 06:46:46 GMT
Cache-control: no-cache,no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Location: http://somesite.com/applicationid.jsp?errormsg=generated application id is B798A0
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=75
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: No. Not unless you have access to the server. First come first served. I'd need a lot more information about the server to help any more than that. Do they restrict certain user agents that look like bots for example? I haven't a clue.

Comment: Thnks man. I have added request & response header in the question. Can u require more info? I can give you, but I want to know about it.

Comment: If you have no server side access, then unfortunately there is no information you can provide. The server would need to be configured to give you priority access. As a client there is nothing you can do. You would need the server administrator to essentially "reserve" a spot for you. Otherwise the server will handle the requests as they are received. In this case it sounds like the server is overloaded and their load balancer gives up trying to route you to a web server. Nothing you can do about that except get your request in before everyone else.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible as I am only a client. I also know that you're right. But still I'm desperate to get some info as these keeps me haunting. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: As a server software developer we go out of our way to prevent what you want to do. It's how people try to "cheat" at things like "first 10 customer" sales. A lot of effort is done on the server side to prevent people from being able to cheat the system and jump to the front of the line. If you find a way to do it, my guess is it won't last long as they'll path their code as soon as they discover what your doing.

Comment: Actually its not cheating, I opose this word. I want to get a page first in a certain time, thats nothing against the rules. You cant bare me from accessing a page before others, when you publish that page. I just want to know if anything works other than simple submitting. However, Thanks for reply.